# Open console window in mono

Tags: c#, mono, console, multiplatform

I'd like my Mono application to be able to open and close a console window at will. I know how to do this on Windows with it's `kernel32.dll` but I'd like it to be platform-independent. If this is not possible I want it to implement different methods for the different OS's.

If it is not possible at all I can always resort to using a self-made console window but that would probably take way longer to implement and won't be as compatible. I really want to be sure whether it's possible or not before I work on a custom console window.

The console window only has to be used for output, no input functionality is required. (It will only feature as a way to show log messages.)

Comment: How about http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics

Comment: I'm trying to manually run a console window, not use the console from the console-application because I'm creating a library.

Comment: What about creating a separate console application behaving as a reader and having your main app spawning these readers and supplying data to them. Pretty sure you can do that easily with named pipes - or any other IPC mechanism. The framework has everything you need ;)
Edit: See the solution 2 on  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/165990/Starting-cmd-exe-in-console-application-in-differe

Comment: mmh it seems that mono doesn't support named pipes. You could however rely on unix socket on non windows machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# to Mono GetConsoleWindow Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824961/c-sharp-to-mono-getconsolewindow-exception)