# C# to Mono GetConsoleWindow Exception

Tags: c#, c++, linux, bash, mono

I'm having some trouble with setting up my application to mono, it gives me a GetConsoleWindow Exception. I thought this would open a new window when you run it on windows, but in Mono, on CentOS 6 with Gnome it gives me this exception.

error code:

`Unhandled Exception:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetConsoleWindow
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Silverwave.Program:GetConsoleWindow ()
  at Silverwave.Program.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00000] in <filename unkno                                                                                        wn>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetConsol                                                                                        eWindow
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Silverwave.Program:GetConsoleWindow ()
  at Silverwave.Program.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00000] in <filename unkno                                                                                        wn>:0
[root@h2297404 Debug]# Unhandled Exception:
-bash: Unhandled: opdracht niet gevonden
[root@h2297404 Debug]# System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetConsoleWindow
-bash: System.EntryPointNotFoundException:: opdracht niet gevonden`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Console windows are specific to Windows systems (that's why [GetConsoleWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175.aspx) does not exist in .NET proper and you had to p/invoke it).

Linux systems do not expose this API, so you cannot invoke it on Linux, and there is no replacement.

Comment: @user, that depends on what you're using that function for. *NIX ttys are not Windows consoles, so you may have to adapt that code anyway, or possibly disable it on *NIX platforms.

Comment: @user, I'm afraid I cannot put this in a simpler way: that "C# emulator" program you're speaking about p/invokes an API function that does not exist on *NIX platforms. The very concept behind the function does not exist there either. If you cannot modify the code of that program, you're SOL.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi what about if you *can* edit the source?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - use Console.WindowWidth

Long answer:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215584/whats-the-name-of-the-environment-variable-with-current-terminal-width

$COLUMNS is one such variable.
Also there's stty -a or more specifically stty size

stty uses

```
    get_terminal_width_height(STDIN_FILENO, &width, &height)
```

which in turn calls

```
    ioctl(fd, TIOCGWINSZ, &winsize);
```

TIOCGWINSZ

Fill in the winsize structure pointed to by the third argument with the screen width and height.
The winsize structure is defined in `sys/ioctl.h' as follows:

```
struct winsize
{
  unsigned short ws_row;    /* rows, in characters */
  unsigned short ws_col;    /* columns, in characters */
  unsigned short ws_xpixel; /* horizontal size, pixels */
  unsigned short ws_ypixel; /* vertical size, pixels */
};
```

Here it is called in mono

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/90972a343b81489e333a379e13f3e0018738e705/mono/metadata/console-unix.c#L177

exported as "TtySetup"

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/92a0ac52a7018199f39f01625eb1025baf564743/mono/metadata/icall-def.h#L130

which is imported here to C# code

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/88d2b9da2a87b4e5c82abaea4e5110188d49601d/mcs/class/corlib/System/ConsoleDriver.cs#L286

```
namespace System {
    static class ConsoleDriver {
    ...
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    unsafe internal static extern bool TtySetup (
        string keypadXmit, string teardown, 
        out byte [] control_characters, out int *address);
```

Here it is called -
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/88d2b9da2a87b4e5c82abaea4e5110188d49601d/mcs/class/corlib/System/TermInfoDriver.cs#L227

unsafe void CheckWindowDimensions ()

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/88d2b9da2a87b4e5c82abaea4e5110188d49601d/mcs/class/corlib/System/TermInfoDriver.cs#L688

And this is available through property WindowWidth:

```
namespace System {
class TermInfoDriver : IConsoleDriver {
public int WindowWidth {
```

of interface IConsoleDriver

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/88d2b9da2a87b4e5c82abaea4e5110188d49601d/mcs/class/corlib/System/IConsoleDriver.cs#L50

Ultimately it should be available through
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/92a0ac52a7018199f39f01625eb1025baf564743/mcs/class/corlib/System/Console.cs#L660

I checked, this works (as of mono 4.0.2.5 at least).

```
using System;
class mainclass {
public static int Main(string[] args) {
Console.WriteLine(Console.WindowWidth);
return 0; } }

sabayon aa $ mcs test.cs -r:System.dll
sabayon aa $ mono test.exe 
239
```